# Getting duplicate records in select query for the Azure DocumentDB

Tags: azure, select, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

I need to write a Select query for the below JSON data in Azure DatabaseDB.

```
{
  "Result": [
    {
      "media": [
        {
          "url": "https://someurl.com",
          "thumb_url": "https://someurl.com",
          "id": "f545f874-a9b4-4573-a0b0-b2d50a7994e0",
          "removed": false,
          "size": 133454,
          "length": 0,
          "type": "IMG",
          "avail": true,
          "has_thumb": true,
          "tagged_chi": [
            {
              "chi_id": "1069b9ef-1028-45f4-b9a1-a40e0d438f4e",
              "tag_x": 262.048,
              "tag_y": 157.472,
              "tag_by": "d481a522-6e2f-4dc6-8aeb-bc87cf27287d",
              "created": 1486723018,
              "last_updated": 1486723018
            },
            {
              "chi_id": "7102fc10-62e8-4d0a-9fcf-35645253fcef",
              "tag_x": 231.648,
              "tag_y": 146.528,
              "tag_by": "d481a522-6e2f-4dc6-8aeb-bc87cf27287d",
              "created": 1486723018,
              "last_updated": 1486723018
            }
          ],
          "created": 1486723012,
          "last_updated": 1486723017
        }
      ],
      "id": "23bcd070-0f64-4914-8bc1-d5e936552295",
      "acc_id": "d481a522-6e2f-4dc6-8aeb-bc87cf27287d",
      "chi_id": "7102fc10-62e8-4d0a-9fcf-35645253fcef",
      "is_note": false,
      "title": "",
      "when": -2147483648,
      "loc_id": null,
      "col_id": null,
      "comment": null,
      "removed": false,
      "created": -2147483648,
      "last_updated": -2147483648,
      "note_type": null,
      "note_value": null
    },
    {
      "media": [
        {
          "url": "https://someurl.com",
          "thumb_url": "https://someurl.com",
          "id": "7665b921-2790-496b-a70f-30afae43d8c6",
          "removed": false,
          "size": 6872977,
          "length": 0,
          "type": "IMG",
          "avail": true,
          "has_thumb": true,
          "tagged_chi": [
            {
              "chi_id": "1069b9ef-1028-45f4-b9a1-a40e0d438f4e",
              "tag_x": 2305.152,
              "tag_y": 686.5653,
              "tag_by": "d481a522-6e2f-4dc6-8aeb-bc87cf27287d",
              "created": 1486976119,
              "last_updated": 1486976119
            },
            {
              "chi_id": "7102fc10-62e8-4d0a-9fcf-35645253fcef",
              "tag_x": 1070.757,
              "tag_y": 1038.741,
              "tag_by": "d481a522-6e2f-4dc6-8aeb-bc87cf27287d",
              "created": 1486976119,
              "last_updated": 1486976119
            }
          ],
          "created": 1486976100,
          "last_updated": 1486976118
        }
      ],
      "id": "58fa3c58-5508-4371-83f4-405332c636e1",
      "acc_id": "d481a522-6e2f-4dc6-8aeb-bc87cf27287d",
      "chi_id": "7102fc10-62e8-4d0a-9fcf-35645253fcef",
      "is_note": false,
      "title": "",
      "when": -2147483648,
      "loc_id": null,
      "col_id": null,
      "comment": null,
      "removed": false,
      "created": -2147483648,
      "last_updated": -2147483648,
      "note_type": null,
      "note_value": null
    }
  ],
  "Continuation": null
}
```

I was trying something like below but it is not working for me. I want the data matched to `Media => tagged_chil => id`

Query suggested by, @peter-tirrell:

```
string.Format("select c.id, c.acc_id, c.chi_id, c.is_note, c.title, c.loc_id, c.media, t from c JOIN m IN c.media JOIN t IN m.tagged_chi where c.chi_id = '{0}' OR t.chi_id = '{0}'", childId)
```

Minor changes in @peter-tirrell's query:

```
string.Format("select c.id, c.acc_id, c.chi_id, c.is_note, c.title, c.loc_id, c.media, t from c JOIN m IN c.media JOIN t IN m.tagged_chi where c.chi_id = '{0}' OR ( t.chi_id != c.chi_id AND t.chi_id = '{0}')", childId)
```

> I am getting duplicate records if the c.child and t.child both are having same values.

Comment: Can you check the response headers and see if continuation token is returned?

Comment: I am getting `[]` as a response.

Comment: Try it with escaped double quotes for the second occurrence so instead of `...{"id": '{0}'}...` you'd have  `...{"id": \"{0}\"}...`. My working theory is that it's using JSON parsing for that part since you wrap it in curly braces to make it an object and JSON requires double quotes even though SQL works with either double or single. If that fixes it, I'll post as an answer and you can accept it.

Comment: it doesn't related to the quotes because other queries are working (which don't have the array ;) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could potentially use `JOIN`s to flatten the structure which might help with querying, too.  Something like:

```
select 
c.id,
c.acc_id,
c.chi_id,
c.is_note,
c.title,
c.loc_id,
m,
t
from c JOIN m IN c.media
JOIN t IN m.tagged_chi
where c.chi_id = {0} OR t.id = {0}
```

Then you can select out whichever specific data fields you need.

Comment: It's working for me, but not 100% I am getting duplicate records if `c.chi_id = {0} OR t.id = {0}` both are same.

Comment: I found some solution here ( http://stackoverflow.com/a/33373782/4025613 ) but I don't know how to use this solutions.

Comment: Yeah, for any sort of aggregate type functionality I've been implementing that in my client code; I'll execute a query like above and then process the results, taking care of duplicates or things like that on my processing end.

Comment: Please post here once you find the solutions :)

Answer (score 0):

Base on my experience, your query code will return null. Because [ARRAY_CONTAINS](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/documentdb_sql/documentdb_sql_array_functions.htm) it will return a Boolean indicating whether the array contains the specified value. That means your query code can be short as `SELECT * FROM TimelineEvent t WHERE OR ARRAY_CONTAINS ( t.media, true)` that will return null in your case.

Please have a try to use the following code:

```
SELECT * FROM TimelineEvent t WHERE  ARRAY_CONTAINS ( t.media[0].tagged_chi, {  
               "id":"0af23202-07f9-40a0-90ba-d2e2f6679331"
             })
```

We also could use UDFs to implement it with customized code, more detail about UDF,please refer to [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-programming#introduction-to-stored-procedure-and-udf-programming).

Comment: I am sorry, but this is not working for me. Let me check the above document link.

Comment: I have updated the code to  `SELECT * FROM TimelineEvent t WHERE  ARRAY_CONTAINS ( t.media[0].tagged_chi, {  
               "id":"0af23202-07f9-40a0-90ba-d2e2f6679331"
             })` in the answer.

Comment: We could get the multiple code sample from the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-dotnet-samples)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you and what if I have multiple items in Media?