# Is there having clause in azure cosmos db? How to use it?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I was trying to write a query which is finding MAX value from all documents. The scenario is something like I have 100 Students Documents, in which student Name, roll number as well as array of Tests inside that array of Subject and its respective marks. So, I am getting highest marks among subject physics from all documents. But I am not getting it with student roll number. That I was trying to find out.

```
TestDoc is:

    Student[
    StudenName:"A",
    StudentRollNo :1,
    id:"1",
    StudentAdd:"---",
    Test1:[
    {
      SubName:"S1",
      Marks:20
    },
    {
      SubName:"S2",
      Marks:30
    },
    ...

    ],
    Test2:
    [
     Same as above
    ],         
    ],

    [
    STUDENT2
    ] ,

and so on
```

Query I am using is:
select MAX(s.Marks) from c join test in c.Test1 join s in test.marks

Comment: You don't actually have 100 documents; you have one document with an array of 100 students. Was that intentional?

Comment: No I have 100 documents of students.

Comment: I think the way I have givn TestDoc is wrong. I have 100 students document.

Comment: What  am finding is if I can get array of marks with student ID as well. Something like : { Marks : 33 , studentId : 1 },{Marks : 23 , studentId : 1 },{Marks : 38 , studentId : 2 }.... Using join Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, you want to implement function like `GROUP BY` in azure cosmosdb queries.

Per my experience, `azure cosmosdb aggregation` capability in SQL limited to `COUNT, SUM, MIN, MAX, AVG` functions. `GROUP BY` or other aggregation functionality are not be supported in [azure cosmosdb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/documentdb-sql-query#Aggregates) now.

However, `stored procedures` or `UDF` can be used to implement your aggregation requirement.

You could refer to a great package [documentdb-lumenize](https://github.com/lmaccherone/documentdb-lumenize) based on DocumentDb stored procedure.

For your first scenario in your post,I created two student documents in my azure cosmosdb account.

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "StudenName": "A",
    "StudentRollNo": 1,
    "Test": [
      {
        "SubName": "S1",
        "Marks": 20
      },
      {
        "SubName": "S2",
        "Marks": 30
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "StudenName": "B",
    "StudentRollNo": 2,
    "Test": [
      {
        "SubName": "S1",
        "Marks": 10
      },
      {
        "SubName": "S2",
        "Marks": 40
      }
    ],
  }
]
```

then I put the resultset searched by SQL below to the `documentdb-lumenize` mentioned above to get the `max` S2 mark.

```
SELECT  c.StudentRollNo,test1.Marks as mark FROM c
join test1 in  c.Test
where test1.SubName='S2'
```

[image]

For your second scenario in your comment,I removed the `where clause` of the SQL above.

```
SELECT  c.StudentRollNo,test1.Marks as mark FROM c
join test1 in  c.Test
```

and `resultset` like:

[image]

This applies only to `one` test.If you want to query `multiple` tests, you could use `stored procedure`.

You could also refer to SO threads below:

1.[Azure DocumentDB - Group By Aggregates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42533067/azure-documentdb-group-by-aggregates)

2.[Grouping by a field in DocumentDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33373198/grouping-by-a-field-in-documentdb)

Comment: Result you are getting is different than me.

Comment: {
  "cubeConfig": {
    "groupBy": "StudentRollNo",
    "field": "mark",
    "f": "max"
  },
  "filterQuery": "SELECT  c.StudentRollNo,test1.Marks as mark FROM c join test1 in  c.Test",
  "continuation": null,
  "stillQueueing": true,
  "savedCube": {
    "config": {
      "groupBy": "StudentRollNo",
      "field": "mark",
      "f": "max"
    },

Comment: "cellsAsCSVStyleArray": [
      [
        "StudentRollNo",
        "_count",
        "mark_max"
      ],
      [
        1,
        2,
        30
      ],
      [
        2,
        2,
        40
      ]
    ],
    "summaryMetrics": {}
  },
  "example": {
    "StudentRollNo": 1,
    "mark": 20
  }
}

Comment: This is what I am getting. I am satisfied with  documentdb-lumenize.
I need to try more things with it.

Comment: It's great for you to get query results by documentdb-lumenize.Thanks for your share.