# CosmosDB: DISTINCT for only one Column

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.deviceId, c._ts FROM c

ORDER BY c._ts DESC
```

I would like to receive only one pair `(c.deviceId, c._ts)` per `deviceId`, but because the `c._ts` value is distinct for all entries, I am getting all the value-pairs for all `deviceIds`, with other words my whole DB.

I have tried to use [Question: Distinct for only one value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021693/distinct-for-only-one-column) as a guide, but I see that CosmosDB does not support GROUP BY.

Is there a way to do this in cosmosDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it's a common requirement i think,i can't implement it on my side as same as you. The distinct keyword can't work on one single column cross whole query result.

`Group by` feature is currently in active development for a long period,based on the latest comment in this [voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/18561901-add-group-by-support-for-aggregate-functions?tracking_code=b30402b00bc499b8fa37845af790cf01),it is coming soon.

If your need is urgent ,as workaround, you could follow this case to use [documentdb-lumenize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46345374/is-there-having-clause-in-azure-cosmos-db-how-to-use-it/46359833#46359833) package which supports Aggregate Functions.