# Delete duplicate documents from DocumentDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

How do I delete duplicate documents based on a document attribute value? For example, documents in a collection are as given below

```
    [  {
    "ProductIdentifier": "A100",
    "ProductTitle": "Product A",
    "_ts": 1491664477
  },
  {
    "ProductIdentifier": "A100",
    "ProductTitle": "Product A"
    "_ts": 1491664466
  }
  {
    "ProductIdentifier": "B100",
    "ProductTitle": "Product B"
    "_ts": 1491664477
  }
]
```

I want to delete the second document as it is the same as first document (based on ProductIdentifier) and has a lower timestamp (based on _ts)

There are quite a lot of such duplicate documents in the collection. What is the efficient way to do it in bulk?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you’d like to group your data and delete duplicates (that with same ProductIdentifier value and lower timestamp) from each group. As far as I know, currently [GroupBy does not be supported in DocumentDB](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/18561901-add-group-by-support-for-aggregate-functions). But you can group the data and get the ProductIdentifier from each group via LINQ, and then query documents with same ProductIdentifier and delete the duplicates.

```
var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<MyDoc>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("testdb", "testcoll")).Where(d => d.ProductIdentifier != "");

List<MyDoc> list1 = query.ToList();

var result = list1.GroupBy(item => new
{
    ProductIdentifier = item.ProductIdentifier,
    ProductTitle = item.ProductTitle
})
.Select(group => new
{
    ProductIdentifier = group.Key.ProductIdentifier,
    ProductTitle = group.Key.ProductTitle
});

foreach (var item in result)
{
    var query1 = client.CreateDocumentQuery<MyDoc>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("testdb", "testcoll")).Where(d => d.ProductIdentifier == item.ProductIdentifier && d.ProductTitle == item.ProductTitle);

    if (query1.Count() > 1)
    {
       //delete duplicates from a group
    }

}
```

Besides, as Larry Maccherone said in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33373198/grouping-by-a-field-in-documentdb), [documentdb-lumenize](https://github.com/lmaccherone/documentdb-lumenize) is an aggregation library for DocumentDB written as a stored procedure, which can help us perform GroupBy.

```
string configString = @"{
    cubeConfig: {
        groupBy: 'ProductIdentifier', 
        field: '_ts', 
        f: 'max'
    }, 
    filterQuery: 'SELECT * FROM c'
}";
Object config = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Object>(configString);
dynamic result = await client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<dynamic>(UriFactory.CreateStoredProcedureUri("testdb", "testcoll", "cube"), config);
//get group info form result.Response
```

Comment: @Alvin PL any updates? Are you able to delete duplicates now?